# How to convert a 2D array of strings and numbers to a numpy float array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My array is 2D numpystr352 and contains a mix of numbers and strings.
I want to convert it to float numpy so that the string elements should convert to `nan` (without using Pandas).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 'tom'], [4, 'Manu', 6]])
```

What I want is:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, nan], [4, nan, 6]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forced conversion of non-numeric numpy arrays with NAN replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223483/forced-conversion-of-non-numeric-numpy-arrays-with-nan-replacement)

Comment: tks for help but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`genfromtext`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223483/forced-conversion-of-non-numeric-numpy-arrays-with-nan-replacement) is not possible with multi-dimensional arrays. On the other hand, you can apply `genfromtext` to each row of the 2D array using [`apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604688/apply-function-on-each-row-row-wise-of-a-numpy-array):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 'tom'], [4, 'Manu', 6]])
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.genfromtxt, 1 ,x))
```

Which will give:

```
[[ 1.  2. nan]
 [ 4. nan  6.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution iterates over the flattened array and checks if each type can be float. If not I will fill in a `np.NaN` instead. After this I will recreate the numpy array with dtype float into the old shape:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 'tom'], [4, 'Manu', 6]])

shape = x.shape
x_nan = np.empty_like(x).flatten()
for i,x in enumerate(x.flat):
    try:
        x_nan[i] = float(x)
    except:
        x_nan[i] = np.NaN

x_nan = np.array(x_nan, dtype=np.float).reshape(shape)
print(x_nan)
# array([[ 1.,  2., nan],
#        [ 4., nan,  6.]])
```