# Readable conversion of 2D-array to string array

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a two-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` of floats. Each row is to be converted to a string consisting of `1`s and `0`s, reflecting whether the elements of the row satisfy a given property or not.
In this question, I will show my approach (which works), then explain why I find it unsatisfactory, and then ask for your advice.

**My approach so far:**

```py
import numpy as np

threshold = 0.1

## This array serves as an example. In my actual code, it
## is bigger: something like shape=(30000, 5).
## That is, 30000 rows and 5 columns. Both numbers will
## from case to case.
test_array  = np.array(
                [[0.5,0.2,0.0,0.0,0.3],
                 [0.8,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2],
                 [0.8,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.1],
                 [1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
                 [0.9,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0],
                 [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.8,0.1],
                 [0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.9],
                 [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0],
                 [0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.0],
                ],
                dtype=float
            )

## Now comes the conversion in two steps.
test_array_2 = np.where(test_array > threshold, '1', '0')
test_array_3 = np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 1, test_array_2)
```

The in-between result `test_array_2` eveluates to

```
array([['1', '1', '0', '0', '1'],
       ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
       ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
       ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0']], dtype='<U1')
```

and `test_array_3` evaluates to

```
array(['11001', '10001', '10000', '10000', '10000', '00010', '00001',
       '00001', '00110'], dtype='<U5')
```

`test_array_3` is the result I want.

**Why this is unsatisfactory:**
I dislike my use of the `str.join()` method. Maybe it is because I'm unexperienced, but it feels like it makes the code less readable.
Also (maybe the more important point), the function `np.apply_along_axis` [is not efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604712/16751401). It would be better to *vectorize the computation*, right?

**Question:**
Is the use of `str.join()` a bad choice and, if so, what other methods are there?
Is there a good way to vectorize the computation?

Comment: You say: `In my actual code, it` `is bigger.` What are the actual dimensions?

Comment: @Armali It will be roughly 30.000 rows and about 5 columns. So the strings I want to get will have a length similar to length 5, as indicated in my question. The number of strings will be much larger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you find this satisfactory or readable, but at least it doesn't use `str.join` nor `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
width = test_array.shape[1]
bytes = np.packbits(test_array > threshold, 1) >> 8-width
array = np.frompyfunc(np.binary_repr, 2, 1)(bytes.flatten(), width)
```

Comment: Thanks for the the idea of using `np.packbits`. Where can I find documentation on the `>>`? I didn't find any so far.

Comment: The documentation of [`numpy.right_shift`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.right_shift.html) says: _The `>>` operator can be used as a shorthand for `np.right_shift` on ndarrays._